# How do I modify Docusaurus appearances of the blog from a component library?

Tags: docusaurus

Creating Modified Blog Entries

I am new to React, and very much to Docusaurus, however, I've managed to get a decent looking DS site going. I am trying to capture some simple snippets to as "blog entries", just small factual snippets, etc. simple project summaries. I’ve hit the limit of the Docusaurus.config options and not sure how to expand the out of box components.

How do I begin to alter and edit Docusaurus to change the Blog page to be like "Cards" in component-speak? Ive seen some example in Infima, but not sure how to bridge that gap?

How can I easily replicate the Announcement Bar to also be at the bottom, like a Banner?

Thank You!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible arena for you to use is [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) — specifically [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/). They have a [card component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/) you could use where you link individual blog entries to that card. If you're comfortable with JavaScript, there's probably an automation you can build there, but hand-coded text is somewhat part and parcel with static-site generators.

If you want a different solution with the CSS code in your `src` file outright, CSSCodeLab has a [React Card layout](https://www.csscodelab.com/react-js-card-layout/) entry with an attached [source code file](https://codepen.io/makmzw/pen/ZjeaRX). Some hand-coded text required, and not automatically integrated with a separate blog setup, but YMMV.

Otherwise Docusaurus' [Showcase](https://docusaurus.io/showcase) page does provide the card formatting. The source code for the page (coded at [`index.tsx`](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/main/website/src/pages/showcase/index.tsx)) as well as the [components](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/tree/main/website/src/components/showcase) are available.